# GA GTM Tags fired on debug mode but doesn't send data

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Regarding universal analytics in google tag manager.

I have setup the same configurations for dev and prod environments but the prod doesn't seems to send data.

When in debug mode, it shows that the tags are being fired but looking at the console (chrome), under the network tab, it should show requests to www.google-analytics.com/collect? but this is not showing on the prod application.

Anyone know what's happening?

[image]

Comment: Errors on the console ? Maybe you explicitly set the GA Cookie Domain to your dev domain. In that case GA cannot set the cookie for the client id on the production domain and will abort. Maybe you can post your configuration for  the Analytics Tag (Screenshot with the UAID blotted out), as at the moment there is not enought info for more than guesswork.

Comment: ive added a screenshot of the configuration. i only have 1 tag for now